# Android: Album Art getting replaced with some image from gallery

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I built a music player app for android. In some songs when I load album art it shows some other image from gallery. It happens rarely and only in some songs even if their album art is not missing. I'm taking album art from `"content://media/external/audio/albumart/" + songId`. I don't understand why it is picking image from gallery from this uri. The song is showing correct image in Google play music app. It happened in a friend's phone. Instead of showing album art this URI is showing his selfie image.

I'm really exhausted trying to debug this issue. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: can you please add your code for picking album art

Comment: @crysis are you picasso for image loading

Comment: @ankitagrawal Yes I'm using Picasso. Is it picasso bug?

Comment: see my answer it is thumbnail framework method bug use my answer to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue with

`Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(contentResolver, id, Kind, options);`method,

sometimes it return random image from sdcard , to workaround it use :

```
public Bitmap findArtworkbyAlbumId(Context activity, String albumId) {
        Bitmap artwork = null;
        if (albumId == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(albumId);
        Log.e("tag", uri.toString());
        ContentResolver res = activity.getContentResolver();
        InputStream in;
        try {

            in = res.openInputStream(uri);
            if (in != null) {
                artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, null);
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return artwork;
    }
```

Comment: I'm using it in recycler view. I'll have to cache the images so I think it's better to use a library. Does Universal Image Loader also have this problem?

Comment: how does parsing albumId to uri gets album art uri?

Comment: albumid is "content://media/external/audio/albumart/" + songId that variable name albumid name is wrong it is path